# Coin Change Using Loops Only, No Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, loops

So I've very recently got started with programming due to one of the subjects I have at class. So far the most complex thing we've learned are loops, we know if, while and for SO I have to manage with that.

In this exercise, program asks for the price of whatever you bought and the money spent. We have unlimited coins of value 50 20 10 5 2 and 1. If you spent more than it costs, the program will give you the change.

Example:
Price?: 44.
Money Paid?: 100.
Change is 56: 50 5 1.

I've tried making it simpler so that I can jump into the whole thing after understanding it.

My logic here was trying to make a similar program but using one coin only.

```
int change, payment, price;
if (payment == price)
            {
                Console.Write("\nNo change needed, you paid with the exact value.\n");
            }
            else if (payment < price)
            {
                Console.Write("\nNot enough money.\n");
            }
            else {
                Console.Write("Change is {0}: ", change);
                 
            
                for (loop100 = 0; loop100 < change; loop100+=100)
                {
                    if (change > 100)
                    {
                        Console.Write(100 + (" "));
                    }
                }
                }
```

Program prints

```
Price?: 1000 /*lets say 1000*/
Payment?: 1500 
Change is 500: 100 100 100 100 100
```

Now, on paper this is what I am looking for. But the issue comes when setting another for loop with a different value. If I copy my for/if loop but changing `loop100` for lets say a `loop50`and setting it up for a 50 value coin, first of all, it goes on a endless loop of 50s, and secondly I wouldnt get the most efficient combination of 100+50 coins but the change with each type of coin. I'd get 100- 5 times and 50- 10 times.

I've put literally hours into this problem and I can't solve it. I looked online and everyone seems to do it with Arrays but my teacher does not want us to use Arrays as we havent learned yet about those and it is much more simple than that.

What kind of for loop should I try? Did I make it too much harder than it already is?

Comment: There are a lot of examples of how to achieve this online.  My preference would be to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to use a `while` loop for this.  Inside that you can use an embedded `if` statement or `for` loop to move through a range of coins values:

```
/// <summary>
/// Ouput the change from the paid amount for the specified price.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="price">An int indicating the price of the purchase.</param>
/// <param name="paid">An int indicating the total amount paid.</param>
private static void outputChange(int price, int paid)
{
    int change = paid - price;
    int[] coins = new[] { 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };

    if (change > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Change: ");
        while (change > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < coins.Length; i++)
            {
                if (change >= coins[i])
                {
                    Console.Write($"{coins[i]} ");
                    change -= coins[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No change needed, you paid with the exact value.");
}
```

This works by finding the next coin that is larger than or equal to the remaining `change`, and then subtracting that value from `change`.  The `while` loop will continue until change is `0` (or below, which is not expected).

Examples:

```
outputChange(44, 100);
outputChange(23, 100);
outputChange(86, 100);
outputChange(100, 100);
```

Output:

```
Change: 50 5 1 
Change: 50 20 5 2 
Change: 10 2 2 
No change needed, you paid with the exact value.
```

**Edit following OP comment**

OP added a comment stating that they would prefer not to use an array for the coins:

> Could the same while+for statement be used by creating a value for
> every single type of coin? I really have to avoid using arrays for now

In this case, another (less elegant) method could use an `if` statement that calculated the next coin, see below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Ouput the change from the paid amount for the specified price.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="price">An int indicating the price of the purchase.</param>
/// <param name="paid">An int indicating the total amount paid.</param>
private static void outputChange(int price, int paid)
{
    int change = paid - price;

    if (change > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Change: ");
        while (change > 0)
        {
            int coin = 0;

            if (change >= 50)
                coin = 50;
            else if (change >= 20)
                coin = 20;
            else if (change >= 10)
                coin = 10;
            else if (change >= 5)
                coin = 5;
            else if (change >= 2)
                coin = 2;
            else if (change >= 1)
                coin = 1;

            if (coin > 0)
            {
                Console.Write($"{coin} ");
                change -= coin;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No change needed, you paid with the exact value.");
}
```

Comment: Could the same while+for statement be used by creating a value for every single type of coin? I really have to avoid using arrays for now.

Comment: @Nijeil I've updated the answer with a second method that utilises an `if` statement to replace the array of coin values

Answer (score 0):

While loop would probably work better. Keep track of how much change is left to deliver.

```
    while( change >= 100)
    {
        change -= 100;
        Console.Write(100 + (" "));
    }
    while( change >= 50)
    {
        change -= 50;
        Console.Write(50 + (" "));
    }
```